# is it possible to force queryset evaluation while keeping it a queryset

Tags: django

I would like to evaluate a queryset once, i.e. fetch the objects to local memory, and then proceed with performing various `filter` commands on the fetched objects.

Of course I could:

- Drop to list comprehensions and other native python syntax, but in many case django ORM's syntax is more readable.
- Skip evaluating the base queryset, but then I'll get a performance hit as I require quite a few `filter` operations later on.

So.. Is it possible to force a queryset evaluation while keeping the result as a queryset object?

Answer (score 5):

How about just doing a `len(myqueryset)`.

or just doing an conditional check can also force evaluate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't keep queryset object when you force it. But you can do something like this:

```
In : list(Project.objects.values_list('owner', 'owner__email'))
Out: [(1, 'admin@example.com')]
```

So, use values_list to keep data that you'll use.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily force an evaluation by iterating the queryset: as long as you ignore the result of the iteration, your object stays a queryset.

```
for item in myqueryset:
    pass
```

However this won't really do what you want, since you say you want to call further filter methods on the evaluated queryset. This can't work, since `filter()` involves modifying the underlying query, and will always hit the database.

I don't know why you think you'll get a performance hit if you skip evaluating the queryset though: the opposite is the case, your proposed evaluation is the unnecessary step.

Comment: `list(myqueryset)` would have the same effect (as long as you don't rebind `myqueryset` of course). Just saying...